# c# Httpclient request working fine on windows 10 returns 403 forbidden on windows 7 (same code)

Tags: c#, windows, httpclient

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler
{
    AllowAutoRedirect = false,
    AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate,
    UseCookies = true,
    CookieContainer = new CookieContainer(),
    UseProxy = false,
    SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12
};

using var client = new HttpClient(handler, true)
{
    Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15)
};

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "*/*");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "API");

using var response = await client.PostAsync(websiteUrl, content, cancellationToken);

if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    return string.empty

return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

The above code works fine on any windows 10 machine I have tested it, but returns a forbidden 403 on windows 7.

Does anyone have any ideas? I have already tried UseDefaultCredentials = true on the handler's initializer but the behavior is still the same.

The **content** is a simple **string json content**.

Comment: What version of .NET? Are you hitting the same server? What TLS protocols are enabled on client and server (and are you using https in the request)? Are the logs of the server when making this request available and do they help? I would suggest using Fiddler and trace on working and nonworking machines (though UseProxy=false may cause a problem with that).

Answer (score 0):

The 403 may be due to Windows 7 not supporting TLS by default:
[How to enable TLS 1.2 on clients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/core/plan-design/security/enable-tls-1-2-client)

> Earlier versions of Windows, such as Windows 7 or Windows Server 2012,
> don't enable TLS 1.1 or TLS 1.2 by default for secure communications
> using WinHTTP.

Check and see if you can enable TLS 1.2 on the Win 7 machine. Or try removing the SSL transport all together:

```
SslProtocols = SslProtocols.None
```

Comment: I enabled TLS 1.2 because it does not work at all in windows 7 without it being enabled since the server uses it as well. Without it enabled I am simply getting a communication error Http exception sadly. Also in my understanding .net automatically supports it if you enabled it like I do in the above code since all other APIs that require TLS 1.2 work fine with just enabling it in code. I will check the registry values as well and let you know.

Comment: @GregoryGR I'd be curious if you figured out why the Win 7 machine's request was failing with the 403.

Comment: Not yet since sadly, your recommendations didn't work either. I am still looking at it I will let you know when I find out.

Comment: Looking forward to hearing what you come up with.